# Error in /~/src/app/app.component.ts (23:8) images is not defined

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a carousel on my app.

**Error Msg given:** Error in /~/src/app/app.component.ts (23:8)
images is not defined

New to angular and trying to follow the guides step by step but it seems like i am missing out something?

Referenced to: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {}

  images = [1, 2, 3].map(() => `https://picsum.photos/900/500?random&t=${Math.random()}`);
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>

<div class="container">

<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly beginner mistake --> Forgot to put the code inside the bracket..

```
export class AppComponent  {
    images = [1, 2, 3].map(() => `https://picsum.photos/900/500?random&t=${Math.random()}`);
}
```

I also changed my codes according to the accepted answer so everything is working fine now :)